# Google Places API, type for party venues?

Tags: flutter, google-places-api, google-nearby

I am working on the mobile app to find nearby venues for different kinds of gatherings, for instance, weddings, baptisms, graduation parties, welcome parties, and so on, for rent. I could not find any types in places API which represent such establishments. Here's, the list of places types offered by places api.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types. If you just use **type=establishments** with NearbySearch API then it'll show everything. I would appreciate the advice, thanks.